# Navigating to a source location from within code

Tags: java, rascal

In a Rascal terminal a source location is clickable.
This will result in navigating to the location and highlighting the code encompassed by the location.

I was wondering how one would achieve navigating to and highlighting from within code.

So instead of having:

```
println("This wonderful source location: <srcloc>");
```

Then clicking in terminal.
Desired is having something more in the lines of:

```
someFunction(srcloc)
```

I have tried using the edit function from IDEservices, however this gives me the following error message:

```
|std:///util/IDEServices.rsc|(26,181,<3,0>,<8,26>): Cannot link method org.rascalmpl.library.experiments.Compiler.RVM.Interpreter.ideservices.BasicIDEServices because: class not found
```

Comment: that definitely looks like a bug. Could you maybe report it here: https://github.com/usethesource/rascal/issues if you have the time? Thanks!

Comment: I think it might be the version of rascal I'm running? 0.18.2 stable release.
*edit: I've filed a bug report.

Comment: thanks @y.reijne

Comment: this one was fixed.